# Separate definition of constant values and dependent parameters in Matlab

Tags: matlab, constants, code-cleanup

In my code, I have a lot of constant values and parameters that take significant space in my code.

For example in **C++**, I would make a header and a separate file where I would define these parameters as, e.g., "`const-type`" and share the header with main or other .cpp files.

How do you keep such structuring in MATLAB, is it worth it?

An example: **Coefficients.m** looks as follows:

```
classdef coefficients
    properties(Constant) 
        % NIST data
        A_N = 28.98641;
    end
end
```

Another file: **Gas.m** where I would like to use `A_N` looks as follows:

```
function Gas()
  clear all
  clc
  
  import Coefficients.* % Does not work

  % A simple print
  Values.A_N        % Does not work
  coefficients.A_N  % Does not work
  Constant.A_N      % Does not work
end
```

Comment: When I have a lot of constants, I use a separate class to hold them all, as shown in [Defining Named Constants](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/properties-with-constant-values.html). Or, depending on what your constants represent and how they are linked, you could use an [Enumeration class](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/enumerations.html)

Comment: @Hoki I see, thanks. Named Constants seem just what I was looking for. Would you create a separate function for them or keep them in so-called main class with all the math computing and graphing?

Comment: yes, I would keep them in a separate class file. As long as the file is in the Matlab path,  you can call them from anytime in your  program. And if some constants are more general (not specific to this program only), they can be used by any program which will need them.

Comment: @Hoki How do you use those values in another m. file? I tried almost everything... Does the Matlab path has to be specified for each .m file or did you refer to keeping all the .m files in the same folder, which I do? I have updated my original post.

Comment: Did you read the documentation link until the end? They have example on how to use these classes after they show you how to define it. In your case, forget the `import` and `header` concept, you simply call the constant at the line where you need it. For your class, just call `Coefficients.A_N` anywhere (in the console, in any script or function) and it will work. Just remove the other bits of code which causes error obviously. Also remember Matlab is case sensitive: `Coefficients` is not the same as `coefficients`.

Comment: @Hoki Yes, I did read the documentation, but `Coefficients.A_N` written inside the `Gas()` function does not work as Matlab cannot resolve it. Of course, I removed the rest, I just put it in the post as an example. This lead me to think about some sort of import, even though Matlab is very distinct from, e.g. C++.

Comment: Your class is named `coefficients` with a lower case first letter (not `Coefficients`). You have to use the exact same case when you want to call it.

Comment: @Hoki I know, I also found this on the internet / Matlab web pages, but somehow it does not work, even though I may sound stupid, but the **Gas.m** simply does not recognize `A_N`  (I tried to put everything before `A_N`...). Would you be that kind please, and add your suggestion to the code in my post, so I am 100 % sure that I understand what you are suggesting, even though I think I do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so assuming the class `coefficients` defined as:

```
classdef coefficients
    properties(Constant) 
        % NIST data
        A_N = 28.98641;
    end
end
```

This code **must** be saved in a file named `coefficients.m` (The class name and file name have to match to avoid weird effect sometimes).

Then assuming the following `Gas.m` file:

```
function Gas()

    % Usage with "disp()"
    disp('The A_N coefficient taken from NIST data is:')
    disp(coefficients.A_N)
    
    % Usage with fprintf
    fprintf('\nFrom NIST data, the coefficient A_N = %f\n',coefficients.A_N)
    
    % Usage in calculation (just use it as if it was a variable/constant name
    AN2 = coefficients.A_N^2 ;
    fprintf('\nA_N coefficient squared = %.2f\n',AN2)
    
    % If you want a shorter notation, you can copy the coefficient value in
    % a variable with a shorter name, then use that variable later in code
    A_N = coefficients.A_N ;
    
    fprintf('\nA_N coefficient cubed = %.2f\n',A_N^3)

end
```

---

Then running this file (calling it from the command line) yields:

```
>> Gas
The A_N coefficient taken from NIST data is:
                  28.98641

From NIST data, the coefficient A_N = 28.986410

A_N coefficient squared = 840.21

A_N coefficient cubed = 24354.73
```

Or if you simply need to access the coefficient in the Matlab console:

```
>> coefficients.A_N
ans =
                  28.98641
```

---

Now all these examples assume that the class file `coefficient.m` is visible in the current Matlab scope. For Matlab, it means the file must be **in the MATLAB search path** (or the current folder works too).

For more info about what is the Matlab search path and how it works you can read:

- [What Is the MATLAB Search
  Path?](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html)
- [Files and Folders that MATLAB
  Accesses](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/files-and-folders-that-matlab-accesses.html)

---

In your case, I would make a folder containing all these sorts of classes, then add this folder to the Matlab path, so you never have to worry again about individual script, function or program calling for it.

Comment: Thanks!! There were actually two issues: **one** was the search path, because I kept the folder on iCloud (moved it recently to have everything backed up), and the **second**: I wanted to use a `global` variable `T` from `Gas()` in `coefficients.m`, and therefore I put a definition `global T` before `classdef coefficients`. This leads me to my last question, if I want to use a `global` variable `T` in my `classdef coeffcicients`, how do I do that, because `Gas.T` does not work, nor writing `global T` before the class definition (it cannot be put inside the class).

Comment: Happy you sorted the path issue. As for the use of a `gobal` variable in a constant class, that seems like a foreign concept to me (and not sure it would work anyway). What is it you want to achieve by declaring anything `global`? Having access to the variable from anywhere? If it's that then having your class definition file in the search path already garantee access to it from anywhere, no need to use global.

Comment: Apologies for such a late reply. By definition of `global` variables I wanted to be able to share those variable between scripts and function, i.e. different *.m file (located in the same folder). While the `coefficients.` before a variable works for using variables in `Gas()` from classdef `coeffcicient`, if I would declare, e.g. `x = 50`; in `Gas()`, I will not be able to use this variable in another *.m file if I don't declare it as a `global x` in the `Gas()` and all the other *.m files. I have the whole file in the MATLAB path, unfortunately, it did not resolve this issue.

Comment: you are talking about a variable `x`, if you need access to it everywhere then `global` could be an option for that (although there are better ways to do that). But what does this variable `x` has to do with your constants ? `constant` values are by definition constant, they are not `variables`.

Comment: I was just giving an example - probably not a great one. My question was if I declare some variable, let's go back to `x`, how do I make it visible for all other *.m files in one folder as you mentioned that "there are better ways to do that" than use `global` variables? I did try to google answer, but no luck so far. I tried some experiments with handle, unfortunately, without any desired result. Thanks.

Comment: If your code grows too much it make sense to use `function` rather than`script`. These `functions` can have input and output arguments, that's how variables are passed around. This is a very generic question and there are several different way to achieve that. You can try to ask a new question about that but you should also provide some context about what your program is doing, and sample code so people can give you more relevant suggestions.

Comment: OK, thanks for the suggestion. I will consider starting a new thread, but this may sound like a too simple question for some :-). I made a few `function`(s) in my code, the thing is that there are few constants that I need to share among them (these are not the `function` outputs) - probably for this specific case, I should put everything to `classdef` (I created the `classdef` after I already had 3 functions and share those constants as a `global` variables).

Answer (score 1):

See [this link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/480829-what-is-the-best-way-to-insure-that-all-of-my-functions-are-using-the-same-constant-values?s_tid=ta_ans_results) for tips on using a class definition for this. Highlights of the tips are:

- Properties can be accessed directly to get the value
- Properties can be added that give the units of the constant (highly advised!)
- Comments can be added that act as help text for the constants
- The doc command automatically creates a reference page for this classdef

E.g.,

```
classdef myconstants
    properties(Constant)
        % g is the gravity of Earth
        % (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth)
        g = 9.8;
        g_units = 'm/s/s';
        % c is the speed of light in a vacuum
        c = 299792458;
        c_units = 'm/s';
    end
end

>> help myconstants.g
```

Comment: If I create a new .m file (within the same folder) and declare this class: `classdef myconstants`, how do I get access to all these constants in other .m files that are in the same folder? I tried to `import` this file, but apparently it does not work as in C++. I found that all files should be put under one package, but I was unable to the define it or specified a correct path. Thanks